# Python script to save bookmarks into a json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, google-chrome

I actually wanted my bookmarks for a text classifier .It needs data in .json format .So i want to know  a python script which will retrieve data from the bookmarks directory and store it in a .json file.(I am using ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome already saves bookmarks in a form of JSON. Your question does not define what is desired outcome so here is a simple code to access and print the whole file of your saved bookmarks on Google Chrome Windows operating system. You will need to do some adjustments to the code as it is designed to run on Windows rather than Ubuntu as I do not have access to it at this moment.

```
import getpass
import json

user = getpass.getuser()
loc = "C:/Users/{}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Bookmarks.bak".format(user)

f = open(loc, encoding="utf8")
data = json.load(f)

print(data)
```

**Edit:**

```
import getpass
import json

user = getpass.getuser()
loc = "C:/Users/{}/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Bookmarks.bak".format(user)

with open(loc, encoding="utf8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

for y in range(0,100):
    try:
        for x in data["roots"]["bookmark_bar"]["children"][y]["children"]:
            print(x["url"])
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: actually I want to use it for a text classifier so I need only the urls of bookmarks but I don't know much about json files also I used one code  I found in github for extracting url only and save it in json but it wasn't working.

Comment: Please see an updated code. This print most of the link from my local bookmarks file. I think your bookmarks file structure is going to be different at least a little bit due to how you have clustered all the urls. Please check this link: https://pythonspot.com/tag/json/ to learn how to parse through JSON structure to get info you need.